# Using Python packages in Azure function code

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I've created an Azure function and want to be able to use various packages in the Python code for the function; take Numpy, for example. Obviously, the code is not going to run from my local machine once it's published to Azure. This means I can't install Numpy to whatever infrastructure it runs on, so I can't import Numpy in my code. How can I use a package like Numpy in the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the official doc:

> Dependencies are obtained remotely based on the contents of the
>   requirements.txt file

All you need to do is create that file and upload it together with your Function code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#python-version-and-package-management

Answer (score 0):

Install python packages from the python code itself with the following snippet: (Tried and verified on Azure functions)

```
def install(package):
    # This function will install a package if it is not present
    from importlib import import_module
    try:
        import_module(package)
    except:
        from sys import executable as se
        from subprocess import check_call
        check_call([se,'-m','pip','-q','install',package])


for package in ['numpy','pandas']:
    install(package)
```

Desired libraries mentioned the list gets installed when the azure function is triggered for the first time. for the subsequent triggers, you can comment/ remove the installation code.